# Как выбрать абсолютный N-ный элемент класса по css-selector-у?

Tags: css, css3, cssselect, css-selection

Вот есть страница. На ней есть група .dragable-area в коих есть дочерние элементы .dragable-item

мне нужен способ с помощью css-selector-а сделать то же самое, что следал бы следующий x-path:

```
//*[@class="dragable-item"][3]

//*[@class="dragable-item"][5]

//*[@class="dragable-item"][N]
```

а

```
.dragable-item:nth-child(3)
```

возвращает не абсолютную позицию, а относительно родительского элемента. Соответственно он возвращает 5й элемент на скриншоте, вместо третьего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для чего-то Cheg-у понадобилась разметка, хотя не пойму для чего. Хотя относительно вопроса она бесполезна, но вот:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
        </div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.document.querySelectorAll(".dragable-item")[2].className += ' need';
```

```css
.dragable-item{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
.dragable-item.need{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
            <div class="item dragable-item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
        </div>
        <div class="dragable-area">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Единственные селекторы которые позволяют выбирать элемент по позиции в DOM - это селекторы `:*-child` и `:*-of-type` (вместо * - last, nth, first) но они оба выбирают по положению относительно родителя. Только средствами css такого сделать не получится. Как вариант просто задавать какой-то дополнительный класс и присваивать его нужному по счету элементу из выборки `window.document.querySelectorAll(".dragable-item");`

Comment: Вот только в вашем примере подсвечивается не 3й элемент, а 4й

Comment: @Cheg а нужно прям именно 3-й? Разве в примере не достаточно указать просто каким образом подсветить какой-либо элемент? В наборе индексация элементов начинается с 0, так что логично что чтоб подсвечивался третий - необходимо заменить циферку 3 на циферку 2. Или это не так очевидно?

Comment: @Cheg хорошо, заменил циферку. Теперь подсвечивается 3-й элемент.